# Prime factors and relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations, prime-factorization

Consider the relation ~ on $ℕ$ defined as follows:

$x$ ~ $y ⇔x * y$ is a square

Interpret x ~ y in terms of prime factors of x and y.

$ x = {P_1}^{n_1}{P_2}^{n_2}{P_3}^{n_3}{P_4}^{n_4}...{P_a}^{n_a}$

$y = {Q_1}^{m_1}{Q_2}^{m_2}{Q_3}^{m_3}{Q_4}^{m_4}...{Q_a}^{m_a}$

Where $P,Q$ are prime

Then

$ {P_1}^{n_1}{P_2}^{n_2}{P_3}^{n_3}{P_4}^{n_4}...{P_a}^{n_a}$  ~  $ {Q_1}^{m_1}{Q_2}^{m_2}{Q_3}^{m_3}{Q_4}^{m_4}...{Q_a}^{m_a}$ $⇔ ({P_1}^{n_1}{P_2}^{n_2}{P_3}^{n_3}{P_4}^{n_4}...{P_a}^{n_a})\times ({Q_1}^{m_1}{Q_2}^{m_2}{Q_3}^{m_3}{Q_4}^{m_4}...{Q_a}^{m_a})$ is a square.

This is as far as I can get. Where do I begin?

Comment: What do you want to verify? Equivalent relation?

Comment: @kelvinhong方 I am supposed to make an interpretation, but I have only rewritten the problem in terms of prime factors. I'm not sure what my professor wants here.

Comment: I see. You can write "for each prime number $p$, its largest power $s,t$ as a factor of $x,y$, respectively, should be both even or both odd. Since we want $s+t$ to be an even integer.